# how to make a new numpy array same size as a given array and fill it with a scalar value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with some random numbers, how can I create a new array with the same size and fill it with a single value?

I have the following code:

```
A=np.array([[2,2],
            [2,2]])
B=np.copy(A)
B=B.fill(1)
```

I want to have a new array B with the same size as A but filled with 1s. However, it returns a `None` object. Same when using `np.full`.

Comment: I don't think you need to do the assigning. So, just `B.fill(1)` would do the job.

Comment: Thank you! Your comment indeed helped me save lots of time!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [`np.full_like`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.full_like.html#numpy.full_like):

```
B = np.full_like(A, 1)
```

This will create an array with the same properties as `A` and will fill it with `1`.

In case you want to fill it with `1` there is a also a convenience function: [`np.ones_like`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ones_like.html#numpy.ones_like)

```
B = np.ones_like(A)
```

---

Your example does not work because `B.fill` does not return anything. It works "in-place". So you fill your `B` but you immediatly overwrite your variable `B` with the `None` return of `fill`. It would work if you use it like this:

```
A=np.array([[2,2], [2,2]])
B=np.copy(A)
B.fill(1)
```