# Create random numpy matrix of same size as another.

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967907/how-to-make-a-new-numpy-array-same-size-as-a-given-array-and-fill-it-with-a-scal) was useful, but mine is slightly different.

I am trying to do something simple here, I have a numpy matrix **A**, and I simply want to create another numpy matrix **B**, of the same shape as **A**, but I want **B** to be created from `numpy.random.randn()` How can this be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`np.random.randn` takes the shape of the array as its input which you can get directly from the `shape` property of the first array.  You have to unpack `a.shape` with the `*` operator in order to get the proper input for `np.random.randn`.

```
a = np.zeros([2, 3])
print(a.shape)
# outputs: (2, 3)
b = np.random.randn(*a.shape)
print(b.shape)
# outputs: (2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks! But what's with the '*'?

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond It unpacks the arguments.  Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python).

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks, TIL.